# ASP.NET(C#) dynamic pages like article.aspx?id=1

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I've been searching around google for hours, but with no luck. What is it called if I want to have a page URL like this article.aspx?id=1 I need a tutorial or something

Thank you :)

Comment: maybe you mean friendly url?

Comment: I mean however the ID changes, there will be some different content on the page, fx article.aspx?id=1 the content will be "Here is content 1" and if you changes the url to article.aspx?id=2 the content will be "Here is content 2"

Comment: They are called "get parameters" or "html query string". In Asp.Net you can reach them like this: `string id = Request["id"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are searching for HTML query string:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string